# Make observeEvent listen for a set of similar elements instead of only 1

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny, backend

I have developed a simple R-Shiny application with custom HTML and I have a set of inputs (within a table) like this:

```
<tr><td>i1</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="i1" name="i1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>i2</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="i2" name="i2"></td></tr>
<tr><td>i3</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="i3" name="i3"></td></tr>
<tr><td>i4</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="i4" name="i4"></td></tr>
```

I need to listen for the changes when the user clicks on any of them and update some values on a matrix. I have read the documentation of Shiny and it says eventExpr is "*A (quoted or unquoted) expression that represents the event; this can be a simple reactive value like input$click, a call to a reactive expression like dataset(), or even a complex expression inside curly braces*" but I do not find how to build such a expression.

I have had to create an `observeEvent` for each one of them like:

```
observeEvent(input$i1, { ... })
observeEvent(input$i2, { ... })
```

...

Is there a posibility to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can addEventListener on the parent node (in this case I guess it would be the table you put these rows into) and check for example:

```
if(event.target.tagName === 'INPUT' && (/i[0-9]/).test(event.target.id)){
    // do your stuff
}
```

It's actually a good practice to avoid appending lots of event listeners on similar nodes and set just 1 listener on the parent node, so +1 for intuition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the +1, but my question is regarding to R (Shiny specifically). Nevertheless, I agree with you.